# How to invoke FVWM-Crystal on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Disappearing windows... I am using my nvidia card for both video and audio. The video port plugs directly into the 4k monitor. The hdmi audio plugs into an hdmi/av converter. This setup causes Ubuntu to think I have 2 monitors, and this is causing video problems and disappearing windows. I am recommended to switch from X11 windowing to FVWM windowing, by installing fvwm-crystal. I installed fvwm-crystal from the repository, but I cannot find instructions how to invoke the fvwm-crystal desktop on Ubuntu 22. Would anybody here know how to invoke the crystal desktop?

Comment: I think the recommendation is dumb but if you want to try anyway and FVWM is correctly installed then you should be able to select it after clicking on your username and then clicking in cog wheel.

Comment: @ChangAn.  Hello and thanks for reply. I ran the install for crystal from the deb, but I see nothing on screen indicating a cog or some such, so cannot invoke yet. I shall investigate this further somehow. Meanwhile, I found a work-around... Using settings, I can change the config to 1 monitor. This solves the problem of windows disappearing. But this also disconnects my audio from the hdmi port, as now all a/v is ported thru DP.